# How many machines would we need to beat google

Tags: linux, windows

how many machines should we approximately have in order to reach Google kind of index in 1 year?also the internet speed & machine configuration
We developing the Crawler in JAVA

Comment: I have no idea, but I hope you have a big budget...

Comment: Why a negative vote?

Comment: You're not serious... are you?

Comment: Even if you did have the machines you'd need tons of knowledge and experience that maybe nobody has.

Comment: i think we have that

Comment: I can imagine the Dilbert boss asking exactly that question.

Comment: Please also take into account the storage and energy requirements :)

Comment: @Iznogood : who is Dilbert Boss?, @FRotthowe :Sure

Comment: -1 because of the combination of over ambitiousness and under specification. Or to quote a famous trope: "if you have to ask, you can't afford it."

Comment: @Alex http://www.dilbert.com/

Comment: If I could vote to close this as "not a real question", I would.  You're looking at at least $1 billion dollars in hardware alone if server numbers are accurate.

Comment: I think this might be a little harder then realize. Companies like Microsoft (Bing), Amazon and ask.com, are asking that same question, and they've only had moderate success. Google has $billions in funding, possibly hundreds-of-thousands of nodes, a dozen datacenters and thousands of staff dedicated to the Google applications. You might want to re-ask this question and be more clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @GregD as ridiculous as that question is its still pretty interesting information.

Comment: I am here for information......may be i cant...but i will try to do it...

Comment: @Iznogood:  may be interesting, but it's not really one that can be answered here without more information

Comment: @Alex try to do what? Get bigger then google? You know if you had an idea to make a better search then google`s maybe it would be worthwhile to try it out but to think you can beat them on hardware and infrastructure is crasy beyond belief.

Comment: @GregD Yeah you are right its more of a discussion topic then question+ clear answer.

Comment: The information may be interesting, but perhaps this question could be asked in a different way which spoke about Google's hardware profile layout. It would be interesting to get some verifiable documentation, and the WP article seems inaccurate and/or out of date.

Comment: Guys, yes the question is too localized and can't be correctly answered as many details will change the answer but try to see how it can be done and you will see that if you only want to do a crawler (no client doing search) and create the index in a year, the job can be totally be done.

Comment: @radius the question is not whether or not it can be done, but what would it take.  It's completely unanswerable...

Comment: @squillman yes I agree and that what I said, it's not answerable but it's possible and from comment/answer I see I understand that some people think "You're stupid, no other one than google can do that"

Comment: @Alex, are you twelve ?

Comment: @Samuel: what do u mean by twelve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trusting http://www.wisegeek.com/how-big-is-the-internet.htm it seems that google has indexed 200 terabytes. If this is exact, with a 100 Mbps connexion you should be able to get 200 TB in a year. But you will have an index with some data that are totally outdated...
Server will totally depend of your crawler performance, and of the way you store data ! (Database used, ...)
Anyway the bigger problem will be the storage I think.

Finally, no one here will be able to give you a correct answer without a complete set of information. You'd better hire specialist in this very specific domain.

Comment: thks for this valuable info......your answer is what i need....thks very much

Answer (score 4):

Look at the current `hardware section` on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_platform) page.

> The combined processing power of these servers might reach from 20 to 100 petaflops.

Comment: This include client request, while he only want to build a crawler. He did not say that he will have billions of client doing queries.

Comment: @Radius Look at the question God:How many machines would we need to beat google

Answer (score 2):

Based on your list of questions on StackOverflow the last weeks I would strongly suspect that you do not have the skills and experience that Google has - not to mention the 10 year headstart - and that is much, much more important than the raw data.

Please notice that even Microsoft cannot catch up, so you will need *more* than them.

Answer (score 1):

From the same [wiki page as jethro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_platform) linked:

> Upwards of 15,000 servers ranging from
>   533 MHz Intel Celeron to dual 1.4 GHz
>   Intel Pentium III (as of 2003). A 2005
>   estimate by Paul Strassmann has
>   200,000 servers, while unspecified
>   sources claimed this number to be
>   upwards of 450,000 in 2006.
>
> One or more 80 GB hard disks per
>   server (2003)
>
> 2–4 GB of memory per machine (2004)

Comment: While interesting, I wonder how much this has changed recently. The WP article claims that Google is super secretive about their datacenters, but their staff seem to publish alot of public whitepapers about the hardware. IIRC, some whitepapers refute the Wikipedia claims above (Many nodes don't have local drives, etc.).

Comment: This include search engine part, while he only want to build a crawler.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thousand, I would assume. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thks....

Comment: way too low....

Comment: @Joris, may be not to only build a crawler. Thousands are probably enough

Comment: Yeah. do not forget that MOST of the load with google is answering queries, not crawling. 1000 decent lower end servers (dual socket etc.) should easily handle a LOT of pages.